# reloadData tableView not calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a viewController with a tableView to show list of my model, but I don't know why the reloadData don't call the cellForRowAtIndexPath for no reason! I implement the tableview dataSource and delegate in the viewDidload() and I'm sure that my tableview is connected with my VC also the numberOfRowsInSection return the correct value

this is My code:

```
protocol UserListDisplayLogic: AnyObject {
    func displayUserList(viewModel: FetchUserList.ViewModel)
}

class UserListViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    // MARK: Properties
    var interactor: UserListBusinessLogic?
    var router: UserListRouting?
    var userList: [DisplayedUserListProtocol]?
    
    // MARK: LifeCycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpView()
        interactor?.getUserList()
    }
    
    // MARK: SetUp View
    private func setUpView() {
        setUpTableView()
    }
    
    private func setUpTableView() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: userListTableViewCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: userListTableViewCell)
    }
    
}

// MARK: TableViewDelegate && TableViewDataSource
extension UserListViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userList?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: userListTableViewCell, for: indexPath) as! UserListTableViewCell
        cell.config(viewModel: userList?[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: UserListDisplayLogic
extension UserListViewController: UserListDisplayLogic {
    func displayUserList(viewModel: FetchUserList.ViewModel) {
        userList = viewModel.displayedUserList
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call displayUserList?

Comment: Is your table view setup with proper constraints? cellForRowAt won’t be called if the table view is not sized correctly.

Comment: I call displayUserList in the presenter( I work with cleanSwift architecture), and I'm sure that is not constraints issue.
this my git repository https://github.com/aymenbraham/CleanSwiftRxSwift please take a look

Comment: You're saying that it (a) definitely calls your tableview(numberOfRowsInSection:) function, (b) that is returning a number > 0, and (c) it never calls your tableview(cellForRowAt:) function... ?   I don't think that's possible. You might think that's what is happening, but one of (a), (b) or (c) has to be not true.

Comment: @BillPatterson this my git repository github.com/aymenbraham/CleanSwiftRxSwift please take a look

Comment: @aymenBraham - what are you doing to try and debug this? If you put `print(userList.count)` before you call `tableView.reloadData()`, do you get your expected count? If you put that line in `numberOfRowsInSection` do you get your expected count?

Comment: @aymenBraham I think you're over-estimating my willingness to offer free help. I'm not going to download your entire project and spend my time debugging it for you....

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the problem with the cellForRowAt method not being called is related to an empty userList or a missing userList object.

In the numberOfRowsInSection method, you are returning userList?.count ?? 0. The ?? operator provides a default value of 0 if userList is nil, so if userList is empty or nil, the numberOfRowsInSection method will return 0.

If userList is empty or nil, then the cellForRowAt method will not be called because there are no rows to display. To confirm whether this is the issue, you can add a print statement in the numberOfRowsInSection method to check if the method is actually being called and if the value of userList?.count is what you expect it to be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfRowsInSection called with count: \(userList?.count ?? 0)")
    return userList?.count ?? 0
}
```

If the value of userList?.count is 0 or nil, then you'll need to ensure that the userList property is properly populated with data before calling tableView.reloadData() in the displayUserList method of the UserListDisplayLogic extension.

**Update**

If the cellForRowAt method is being called but the cells are not being displayed correctly, setting a breakpoint on the 'cell.config(viewModel: userList?[indexPath.row])' line and using the View Debugger can help identify any issues with the cell design.

To use the View Debugger, you can follow these steps:

1. Run your app in Xcode and navigate to the view with the table view.
2. Once the app is running, go to the Xcode menu and select "Debug" > "View Debugging" > "Capture View Hierarchy".
3. Xcode will then display a 3D representation of the view hierarchy. You can select any view in the hierarchy to see its properties and constraints.
4. Find the cell that corresponds to the indexPath you're interested in by selecting the table view and navigating to the correct section and row.
5. Once you've selected the cell, you can inspect its properties and constraints to see if anything is incorrect or missing.
6. You can also use the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in the bottom right corner of the 3D view to highlight any constraints that may be causing layout issues.

**Update**

Another possibility is that the tableView is not being reloaded on the main thread. You can try wrapping the reloadData() method call in a DispatchQueue.main.async block to ensure that it's being called on the main thread, like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Update**

After reviewing your project code, I have determined that the issue is related to redundant creation of the main view controller. The controller being displayed lacks configuration with interaction and presenter components, which is why you're only seeing a white background. The properly configured controller exists in memory but is not being displayed in the main window.

To resolve this issue, there are two steps you can take. Firstly, avoid creating the default view controller by the app. You can achieve this by removing the "StoryboardName" key in "Project->Info->Custom iOS Target Properties->Application Scene Manifest->Scene Configuration->Application Session Role->Item 0 (Default Configuration)".

Secondly, build and configure the main view controller in SceneDelegate rather than in AppDelegate. To do this, remove the code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and instead write the following lines in scene(_:willConnectTo:options):

```
let viewController = UserListScene.initialization.configure()
scene.windows.first?.rootViewController = viewController
```

I have used the memory debugger to identify the problem.

Comment: the userList is not nil and  userList?.count return the correct value but I tried to call tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0), with: .none) after the tableview.reloadData() the numberOfRowsInSection  is called but I don't know why the tableview is still empty!!

Comment: I did the debug view hierarchy but nothing show up , I waited more than 20 mn !! 
I don't think it's a constraints issue because the cells appear when i change the numberOfRowsInSection returnedValue userList.count  to 10 
this my git repository  https://github.com/aymenbraham/CleanSwiftRxSwift 
please take a look